# WPF - GridAnimation but "MVVM-ized"

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, storyboard

I've made a fairly decent Grid Animation that works well (even when you spam click button interrupting the animation midway) but now I want to convert it using the MVVM approach. (Just recently learned about it... was doing everything in code-behind until recently...)

What I've tried is setting triggers and the storyboard inside the button but I think this limits some features (spam clicking has some bugs). What I've seen as possible options are setting the DataContext for each of the Buttons firing the commands (making it possible to use multiple DataContexts - one for the ViewModel, and one specifically for the GridAnimation), or something like 'nesting' or creating a parent-children relationship with the Models and ViewModels somehow (but I can't quite wrap my head around this one yet as I have just recently discovered MVVM). I was wondering if there were more optimal approaches.

https://github.com/Ravidelle/GridAnimation

rtGridAnimation - code-behind working version

vmGridAnimation - attempted MVVMed version, very buggy

Comment: I don't think there is an MVVM way since animation is a view concern so the ViewModel is not supposed to be aware of it. If there is some other business logic in there it should indeed go to the ViewModel but I think the animation logic shouldn't. Was it just the animation logic you wanted to move ?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the proper way of saying it. I want the business logic and animation logic separate from each other. Is there a specific topic or term for this? Or a proper way of separating/implementing animation logic?

Comment: Thinking about MVVM way, you might consider to move your code on a custom control and use behavior (linked maybe preview click) to handle animation stuff and let the use Bind button click to ViewModel for business logic